# disable scroll / fixed panel jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, scroll

I am using jquerymobile framework and i would like to stop scrolling conent while panel (menu) is open.
on this page: http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#option-positionFixed
it says how to position it to fixed, however you can still scroll down.

many thanks

Comment: data-position-fixed="true" works fine for me but the body or .ui-content still is scrollable.